# How to remove square brackets and add each word into different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file that contains multiple values in it like:

```
[text] [text2] [text3] [text4] [text5] [text6]
[text] [text2] [text3] [text4] [text5] [text6]
[text] [text2] [text3] [text4] [text5] [text6]
[text] [text2] [text3] [text4] [text5] [text6]
```

I want to remove all square brackets and store these values in different columns. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the delimiter, tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['[text]','[text]','[text]','[text]'],
        ['[text]','[text]','[text]','[text]'],
        ['[text]','[text]','[text]','[text]']]
t = pd.DataFrame(data)
t
```

[image: File]

You can use the given code snippet:

```
t.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[|]'))
```

[image: End Result]

Explanation:

- `.apply()` function applies a function to every element of data frame
- `lambda x: x.str.strip('[|]')` this function strip '[' or ']' from left or right of a string.

Comment: the data is stored in a CSV file is there any way through which I can use that file to give me output like you showed above

Comment: Yes, instead of t = pd.DataFrame(data) do it like t = pd.read_csv(“path_to_csv”) and run the second code block.